# Emacs ignoring global keybindings

Tags: key-bindings

I am working on a very old Emacs version (23.2.1). I am trying to  bind `C-C C-i` to an interactive command without luck.

The command selects code regions delimited between two lines that start with `##`. It **works well** when I call it interactively (`M-x python-select-cell`), but the keybinding does **not** work in Python buffers:

```el
(defun python-inside-comment-p ()
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line 1)
    (looking-at "^#")))

(defun python-select-cell ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char
   (if (re-search-backward "^\\s-*##[^#]" nil t)
       (match-end 0)
     (point-min)))
  (while (and (python-inside-comment-p)
              (eq 0 (forward-line 1)))
    nil)
  (set-mark (point))
  (goto-char
   (if (re-search-forward "^\\s-*\\(##[^#]\\)" nil t)
       (- (match-beginning 1) 2)
     (point-max))))
```

Global keybinding:

```el
# Binding
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-i") 'python-select-cell)
```

I have also tried setting up a hook without luck

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    #'(lambda ()
          (global-set-key (kbd "C-C C-i") 'python-select-cell)))
```

What could be going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modes can define their own key bindings (and most do). Key bindings defined by a mode hide global bindings. Python mode binds `C-c C-i` (to `python-find-imports`), so its binding hides yours. This is explained in more detail in the manual in the section on [local keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Local-Keymaps.html#Local-Keymaps).

You can check what a key does in the current context (e.g. in the current mode) by pressing `C-h c` (`describe-key-briefly`) or `C-h k` (`describe-key`) then typing the key (or key sequence). There's no easy way to look up where a particular binding was made, but you can list the bindings made by the current major mode and active minor modes with `C-h m` (`describe-mode`).

There are conventions for key bindings in Emacs. I can't find them in the Emacs manual, they're buried in the Elisp manual under [major mode conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html#Major-Mode-Conventions): `C-c` is the prefix that is left free in Emacs; `C-c C-letter` is conventionally for major modes, and `C-c letter` is conventionally for the end-user. As the end-user, expect major modes to often override `C-c C-letter` bindings.

If you want your command to be bound globally, you should bind a different key, such as `C-c i`.

If you want your command to be bound only in Python mode, you need to define it in the Python mode keymap, `python-mode-map`. The keymap doesn't exist until Python mode is loaded, so you need to delay until this happens. Use [`eval-after-load`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html) (or the `with-eval-after-load` wrapper in recent versions of Emacs):

```
(defun josh-after-load-python ()
  (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-i") 'python-select-cell))
(eval-after-load "python" '(josh-after-load-python))
```

This will, of course, shadow the binding for `python-find-imports`. If you care about that command, you may want to pick a different key.

Comment: Perfect. Super helpful, right the point, and solved the problem.