# How to Remap `org-mode` key bindings?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

As mentioned in this question, I can not use org mode properly within tmux. So, I would want to remap key bindings like `alt+RET` for creating a new bullet item or `shift + left/right arrow` to change an item hierarchy.

How would I do that?

Comment: The question is too generic. @Alevardi What have you tried so far? Have a look [this recent answer on emacs.SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/23801/115). That answer is for `python-mode-map` but the same steps to figure out the default bound command, and redefine the binding using `define-key` applies in your case too.. just that now it is `org-mode-map`.

Comment: Many of us read both forums, so please choose just one forum and avoid cross-posting.  This one is generally more forgiving, so if someone already voted to close, that is a sign you should probably spend some time editing the question.  The other forum is a bunch of serious hard-core programmers that insist on hard-core programming questions -- e.g., sample code of what almost works . . . .

Answer (score 1):

See the Info page ["(org) TTY keys"](http://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html) for alternative chords for various Org chords.

The listed [speed keys](http://orgmode.org/manual/Speed-keys.html#Speed-keys) must be activated separately.