# Stop later modes from clobbering a "global" keybinding

Tags: key-bindings

I use ace-window to change windows, with `M-o` as my key-binding.

However, when I enter a window that is in HTML mode, this gets clobbered to "set face."  I'm now stuck in this window, and can't `M-o` my way back out.

I have the following in my ace-window config, which specifies the key is global:

```
(use-package ace-window
  :init
  (setq aw-keys '(?a ?s ?d ?f ?g ?h ?j ?k ?l))
  (setq aw-dispatch-always t)
  :config
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'ace-window)
  )
```

How can I stop html-mode for now, and /any/ mode in general, from clobbering the global keybinding?

I'm generally learning about key-bindings from [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs).

### update

This was marked a duplicate but it’s not clear to me how to apply the links to this problem. I didn’t load markdown-mode in my init.el as these suggest editing—it automatically clobbered my keybindings with defaults without any loader.

What I’m looking for in this question is specifically how can I make the keybindings in ace-jump un-overwritable, even if rogue modes load themselves after.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  See here, for example: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23800/emacs-ignoring-global-keybindings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emacs ignoring global keybindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23800/emacs-ignoring-global-keybindings)

Comment: See [Searching the Active Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html): the global keymap is the last keymap to be looked at, so if a higher-precedence keymap binds the key, that's what you will end up with. So they don't really clobber the global keybinding: they just shadow it.

Comment: Thanks, I don’t understand how to use those links to answer my particular problem. Do I need to load the keybindings differently for ace-jump? I don’t even have markdown-mode in my init.el, so I don’t see what I have to write there. This was just default behavior.

Comment: The link was meant to help you understand why that was happening, not to help you deal with the immediate problem (that's why it was a comment, not an answer). As for an answer, I suspect that you will have to play whack-a-mole with each mode that uses the `M-o` keybinding, Alternatively, you can find an unused key to bind `ace-window` to (`M-o` is just a suggestion). The dupe that @FranBurstall has pointed out tells you about the Emacs conventions for user-defined keybindings (basically `C-c <letter>` should never be used by packages, so that is a safe choice).

Comment: Is there any kind of immutable keybinding? Or is there hook where I could add a function that after any keybinding in a package, could call back my ace-jump global keybinding and reset it back to what I want?

Comment: As to an immutable keybinding, the answer is "no", but that is not the problem you have (as I tried to explain): the keybinding in the global map is not changed - it is still there, but it is shadowed by a keybinding in a different map that is of higher priority. As for a hook, I don't think that packages do that in general, so even if some did, it would still be a whack-a-mole thing.  Your best bet IMO is to use a "safe" keybinding in the global map (maybe `C-c o` to make it as similar to `M-o` if you are inclined that way).

Comment: In your update you say "What I’m looking for in this question is specifically how can I make the keybindings in ace-jump un-overwritable, even if rogue modes load themselves after." and as explained, *there is no way to do that*. Even with an overriding keymap as in @FranBurstall's answer, a "rogue" mode can add its own overriding keymap, so it can *always* throw a wrench into the machinery.  That is why Emacs reserves some keys that *by convention* packages will not use, but even here a rogue package can flout the convention and cause havoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry: I was reluctant to add to the gazillion "`global-set-key` does not work" answers but the comments indicate that I did not say enough.  Anyway, here is an actual answer:

1. By now it should be clear that the `global-keymap` is at the bottom of the keymap hierarchy and will be overridden by almost any other keymap.
2. There is however a solution for `use-package` users:

```lisp
(use-package ace-window
  :demand t
  :init
  (setq aw-keys '(?a ?s ?d ?f ?g ?h ?j ?k ?l))
  (setq aw-dispatch-always t)
  :bind*("M-o" . ace-window))
```

This invokes the `bind-key` package which provides an over-riding keymap. Do `C-h P bind-key` for more information.