# How to unbind a key bound by org-mode-map?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I'd like to bind `jump-to-register` with `C-'`, like this: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'jump-to-register`.

However, `C-'` is already bound to `org-cycle-agenda-files`.

I tried to unbind `C-'` with `(global-unset-key (kbd "C-'"))` but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `global-set-key` sets the global keymap which is overridden by every other keymap including `org-mode-map`.  See this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75204/stop-later-modes-from-clobbering-a-global-keybinding) (out of many) for a recent discussion.

Comment: Is `global-unset-key` also overridden? How to unbind a key bound by `org-mode-map` then?

Comment: Your question is, as you say in your comment, **"How to unbind a key bound by org-mode-map "**. That's no doubt a duplicate question.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you very much. Here is the proper solution : `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-'") nil)` and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'jump-to-register)`

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```lisp
(define-key (current-global-map) [remap org-cycle-agenda-files] 'jump-to-register)
```

Explanations:

> **Remapping Commands**
>
> You can tell Emacs that you want to replace all
> keys pointing to a certain command with one of your own choosing by
> using the remap notation.
>
> You must do this instead of passing a key to the key bind function you
> are using. This is the best way of replacing existing commands with
> your own, as Emacs does the hard work of figuring out all the keys it
> needs to rebind.

Source: [Mastering Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs)

EDIT:

Here is a preferable solution:

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-'") nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'jump-to-register)
```